# How to iterate over a Tree in Scalaz

Tags: scala, tree, scalaz, tree-traversal

The Scalaz Tree class proves seemingly very useful `Zipper' functionality via TreeLoc [(Javadoc)](http://docs.typelevel.org/api/scalaz/nightly/index.html#scalaz.TreeLoc).

However, it's not apparent to me how to easily iterate through a tree (e.g. to find the `k-th' node in a tree containing a total of n>k nodes) without doing a lot of conditional hedging on whether the zipper is at the end of the list of current children.

Is there an easy way to do this that I'm missing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Stealing from the [`TreeLoc.find`](https://github.com/scalaz/scalaz/blob/series/7.3.x/core%2Fsrc%2Fmain%2Fscala%2Fscalaz%2FTreeLoc.scala#L76) method, you could do something like this:

```
  def findAt[A](tree: TreeLoc[A], k: Int): Option[TreeLoc[A]] = {
    Cobind[TreeLoc].cojoin(tree).tree.flatten.drop(k).headOption
  }
```